# What is a logical buffer in the context of OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, graphics

I was reading [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318339%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on framebuffers and it mentions: "The framebuffer consists of a set of logical buffers: color, depth, accumulation, and stencil buffers."

What does the article mean by "logical buffers". In particular I'm confused by the use of "logical". As opposed to what other type of buffer?

Answer (score 4):

I think it means that physically, there's one big buffer (framebuffer), but it's logically divided into different parts storing different types of data.

Answer (score 1):

The logical buffer is a data surface that can be rendered to. It's an abstraction between Texture and Renderbuffer.